# SortByCount and display every documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to know if is it possible in addition to what my code does bellow, to display every document that is counted.

```
db.getCollection('mflix_movies').aggregate([
    {"$unwind" : "$countries"},
    {"$sortByCount" : "$countries" }
])
```

It is the result of the query above :

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : "USA",
    "count" : 11855
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : "France",
    "count" : 3093
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : "UK",
    "count" : 2904
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : "Germany",
    "count" : 1659
}
```

I want to display also the 11855 documents of USA, the 3093 documents of France, etc...  I want this to be displayed at the bottom of each count

Comment: your question is not clear can you elaborate this => *I want for example to have also all the 11855* more.

Comment: I edited, is that clearer ?

Comment: are you sure? it is not good idea, if you add thousands of documentd in a single document it will be exceed the memory limit of 16MB, see [aggregation pipeline limits](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-limits/#aggregation-pipeline-limits).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer :

```
db.getCollection('mflix_movies').aggregate([
{ $unwind : "$countries" },
{ $group: { _id: '$countries', Films: { $push: { Titre: '$title' } }, Total: { $sum: 1 }}},
{ $sort: { Total: -1 } }
])
```